# Dll missing the expected functions

Tags: excel, vba, dll, dllimport, declare

According to the MSDN documentation, the [propvarutil.h](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/propvarutil/) header file which resides in the Propsys.dll library (I think) defines a set of functions `InitVariantFrom...` - e.g [`...FromBoolean`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/propvarutil/nf-propvarutil-initvariantfromboolean)

However when I look at the dll (located at `C:\WINDOWS\system32`) in dependency walker, I see that some of the `InitFrom` functions are missing:

[image]

i.e. we have `FromBooleanArray` but not plain `FromBoolean`

Why is this, and how do I access the methods defined in that header when all I have to play with is this dll?

Comment: Just look at the .h file, you'll see these are inline functions and defined only when compiling a C++ program.

Comment: @HansPassant sorry, quite new ground so this may be super obvious - but isn't a dll the compiled C++ program? I thought headers just describe empty functions/ a public interface to the .cpp file, so would be wrapped up in the dll in some way?

Comment: Well, no, providing the function inline is not completely unusual.  This kind of shell programming is purely in the domain of C++, Microsoft won't support anybody trying to use a different language runtime.  You didn't get great advice on your previous question.  Tends to happen when you don't explain why you want to solve a problem.  Consider letting VBA do the job with Public Function CopyObject(ByVal obj As Object) As Object / Return obj / End Function.  But you would have already considered that so very hard to tell why you want to do it another way.

Comment: @HansPassant Ok, I think I get the bit about inline functions and header files; the header actually defines implementations of some functions inline, not just empty templates. Still not 100% sure why that header doesn't make its way into the dll though. Regarding the other question; I don't just want to Copy Variants to other Variants (Object is VB.Net's equiv of Variant, sort of). No, I want to read strongly typed data into a Variant - useful when all I have is an address and type, i.e. the variable isn't VBA's. I've [updated to clarify](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58923075)

Comment: Oh I see, is it in the `#ifdef __cplusplus` line? I assumed these were some conditional compilation arguments that dictate what does/ doesn't end up in the dll that just depend on which compiler was used. But are they in fact used to detect the caller language at runtime or something to that effect?